# Invalid Characters in JSON after unicode conversion

Tags: python, json, django, parsing, unicode

I've been trying to send parsed JSON data from the server side (in python) to the client side of my Web app where it can be stored and then displayed on the page. For some reason, when the data gets to the client side, it has weird characters on both ends of it. These characters are causing a problem when I'm trying to iterate through each list of data that I have as I need to find the length of a list. None of these strings can even successfully be output to the console. I looked up many posts on SO and elsewhere for stripping unicode from strings, using the ast library or simply just using the `.encode()` function, but nothing has resolved this issue so far.

As I am using the Django framework, the data is being parsed on the serverside and passed to the client side through context variables.

Here is the original js code on the server for what I'm trying to do:

```
var $divline = $("<div id = ticketObj></div>");
    console.log("length of artist list" + {{venue_names}}.length );
    for(var i = 0; i < {{venue_names}}.length; i++){
        
        $divline.append('Artist ' + {{form_artistSelect}} + '  Location: ' {{venue_cities}}[i] ', '{{venue_region}}[i]' Venue: ' + {{venue_names}}[i]
     ); 
    
    }
    var $resultObj = $('<div id = "inviteObj" style="margin:100px"></div>');
    $resultObj.append($divline);
    $resultObj.appendTo($("#results"));
```

Here is the page source version of the same code:

```
 var $divline = $("<div id = ticketObj></div>");
    for(var i = 0; i < Miike%20Snow.length; i++){
        
        $divline.append('Artist ' + Miike%20Snow[i] + '  Location: ' [&#39;Miami&#39;, &#39;Miami&#39;, &#39;Miami&#39;] ', '[&#39;FL&#39;, &#39;FL&#39;, &#39;FL&#39;]' Venue: ' + [&#39;Ultra Music Festival&#39;, &#39;Ultra Music Festival&#39;, &#39;Ultra Music Festival&#39;] ); 
    }
    var $resultObj = $('<div id = "inviteObj" style="margin:100px"></div>');
    $resultObj.append($divline);
    $resultObj.appendTo($("#results"));
```

In the python view, I simply getting the JSON and parsing it like this:

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

        #titles = [ i.get("title") for i in data]
        raw_dts = [i.get("datetime").encode("utf-8") for i in data]
        
        #formatted_dts = [i.get("formatted_datetime") for i in data]
        ticket_urls = [i.get("ticket_url").encode("utf-8") for i in data]
        ticket_statuses = [i.get("ticket_status").encode("utf-8") for i in data]
        venue_names = [i.get("venue").get("name").encode("utf-8") for i in data]
        venue_cities = [i.get("venue").get("city").encode("utf-8") for i in data]
        venue_region = [i.get("venue").get("region").encode("utf-8") for i in data]
```

***Regardless*** of what method of conversion I use, I'm still getting those problematic characters once the code is sent to the client.

This problem should be pretty straight forward to solve but there's something small that's most likely going on and its holding up other work. How should I go about resolving this issue?

#### EDIT:

In the html for the page, I have the form and underneath it I have a div named container:

```
<form id = "search" method= 'POST' action = ''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }} 

<input type= 'submit' value= 'Submit'>
</form><br>
<div id = "container">
```

I then try to append an unorderd list to the div and to the list I try to append list elements, but for some reason, nothing is being appended:

```
var venues = {{venues|safe}};
console.log("length of artist list" + venues.length);
var $list = $("<ul  class='list-group'>");
for(var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++){
    
    $list.append("<li class='list-group-item'>Artist {{form_artistSelect}}  Location: " venues[i].city ', 'venues[i].region' Venue: ' + venues[i].name + "</ul>"); 
}
// var $resultObj = $('<div id = "inviteObj" style="margin:100px"></div>');
// $resultObj.append($divline);
$list.appendTo($("#container"));
```

Comment: What is `form_artistSelect` here?

Comment: ```form_artistSelect``` is the artist name that the user enters into the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a JSON issue. This is an issue with how you generate your JavaScript. You are trying to treat string data as JavaScript objects.

Moreover, those are *Python* data structures, not JSON lists, because you decoded them already. There is also no need to encode everything to UTF-8 here. Last but not least, you could just leave the venue structure as dictionaries / JSON objects as you don't need those lists separately.

You'll need to convert your lists back to JSON to insert them as JavaScript list literals into your generated JavaScript, so that you can then treat them as JavaScript objects (once the browser has parsed those literals).

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

raw_dts = json.dumps([i["datetime"] for i in data])

ticket_urls = json.dumps([i["ticket_url"] for i in data])
ticket_statuses = json.dumps([i["ticket_status"] for i in data])
venues = json.dumps([i["venue"] for i in data])
```

and your template:

```
var $divline = $("<div id = ticketObj></div>");
var venues = {{ venues|safe }};

console.log("length of artist list" + venues.length );
for(var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++){

    $divline.append('Artist {{form_artistSelect}} Location: ' +  venues[i].city + ', ' + venues[i].region + ' Venue: ' + venues[i].name
 ); 

}
var $resultObj = $('<div id = "inviteObj" style="margin:100px"></div>');
$resultObj.append($divline);
$resultObj.appendTo($("#results"));
```

Here the `{{ venues|safe }}` line tells Django to not HTML-escape the values, because they have already been encoded to JSON instead.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a good solution, but I'm still running into some problems with outputting the JSON data. I changed the code slightly so that it would create a list item for each ticket, append that to an unordered list, and then append that to a div. For some reason, its not displaying anything. I'll update the post with the code that I added.

Comment: @loremIpsum1771: your JS syntax is invalid, you need to use `+` to concatenate strings. You'll almost certainly have an error message in your JS console about that.

Comment: @loremIpsum1771: you are also adding a closing `</ul>` for every item you are adding to the `<ul>` tag. You probably wanted to use `</li>` instead.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I don't know how I forgot to add the plus signs between the strings... Thanks!